# Justification for the power series representation of exponential function

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, exponential-function

In the book of *Complex Analysis* by Conway, on page $32$, it is given that

> Consider the series $\displaystyle \sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\:\frac{z^n}{n!}$ ;we have that this series has radius of convergence $\infty$. Hence it converges at every complex number and the convergence is uniform on each compact subset of $\mathbb{C}$. Maintaining a parallel with calculus, we designate this series by
> $$e^z =\exp z= \sum_n^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!},$$ the *exponential series of function*.

However, the author states the fact
$$e^z = \sum_n^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!}$$
as if is it a definition or just a notation, but $e^z$ has a meaning prior to the above statement, so shouldn't the author show the equality of LHS to RHS in here ?

If so, how can we show this ?

Comment: Not a definition. Just an extension of the symbol. Justified by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is simply the definition of $e^z$, the complex exponential. What the author did before is showed that the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!}$ converge for any number $z\in \mathbb{C}$. If that wasn't the case then the definition of $e^z$ would make no sense.

Answer (score 3):

This *is* a definition. You stated that $e^z$ had a meaning prior to the statement, but that is not true. The expression $e^z$ appears here for the first time in Conway's textbook.

Comment: I don't think so. Calculus is explicitly mentioned, thus there is a prior meaning and therefore the word *designate* instead of *define*.

Comment: @gammatester, from calculus we know that $e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$ for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$. And this is the reason why it makes sense to define the complex exponential $e^z$ with $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!}$. That's what the author means. But it is still a definition.